# Issues with signing my application apk file

Tags: android, permissions, java

This will be my first time signing application using Keytool and Jarsigner.

I run my apk through the market signing process, step by step as it is explained in android official site

https://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Signed process finished with success apk created.
Installation of this apk on Nexus One also passed, but when I try to launch it from Nexus One, I got Permission Denial error.

Please help.

I add here a complete error: BTW I run my tests from apk because they are written with Instrumentation.

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation Compon
entInfo{com.android.phonetests/com.android.phonetests.PhoneInstrumentationTestRu
nner} from pid=4598, uid=4598 not allowed because package com.android.phonetests
 does not have a signature matching the target com.android.phone
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```

Comment: What environment are you using? If you are using Eclipse you can debug on your device and not have to do any manual signing or apk installation.

Comment: Ups! you have to align your app since you had this message "thats not allowed because package com.android.phonetests does not have a signature matching the target com.android.phone", use:  zipalign -v 4 "C:\Android\Apps\MyAppNotAligned.apk" "C:\Android\Apps\MyAPP.apk"

Comment: if you still havin troubles post your Manifest.xml!=)

Comment: Hi Jorgesys

I have performed alignmnet for my apk file using this command:

Comment: Hi Jorgesys I have performed alignment for my apk file using this command: 
zipalign -v 4 myapplication.apk myapplication_algn.apk

created: myapplication.apk file

I succeeded to install and run it on our embedded platform 
I succeeded to install it on Nexus One BUT failed to run it and got same errors associated with Permission Denial 

Sorry 
What can you suggest ?

Comment: Jorgesys 

I can't post my manifest file due to characters amount limitation 
Can I send you it by email ?!

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get every permission simply by asking for it; there are many permissions which require a specific signature (normally the system's platform signature) in order to be granted.

Uninstall your application, then install it while monitoring logcat. Look for messages that indicate recognition of a requested signature but a denial of it being granted.